# Getting error when i set EnableSSL= false

Tags: c#, email, ssl, sendmail

I am getting error "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. u78sm8177860pfi.2 - gsmtp" if i change EnableSSL= false. Although it works absolutely fine if i set (EnableSSL=True) it to true. But due to business requirement i have to keep EnableSSL=false. Can you help me how can i send email by keeping EnableSSL = false. Below is my code.

```
var smClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
MailMessage lMail = new MailMessage();

// Create Mail

msg.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("do_no_reply@abc.com", "Scs");
msg.Subject = "Send Email with EnableSSL set to false";
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
msg.Body = "Test body";

msg.To.Add(recieptents);
// port="25" enableSsl="false" 
 smClient.Port ="25";
smClient.EnableSSL="false"
smClient.Send(lMail);
```

below are setting using to send email.

```
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="devdotnet06@gmail.com">
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="25" enableSsl="false" 
  userName="devdotnet06@gmail.com" password="*****" 
 defaultCredentials="false"/>

  </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
```

Comment: Are you able to elaborate on the reason you have to keep SSL disabled?

Comment: That's a really odd business requirement... "We restrict you from using more secure protocols!"

Comment: "The SMTP server requires a secure connection" vs "EnableSSL = false": I think your problem is here. You either need to change the SMTP server for one that does not require a secure connection (which will be a bad move and voids all your devops karma points) or you need to stop doing "EnableSSL = false".

Answer (score 2):

It won't work so you'll need to use a different SMTP server if thats truly a business retirement.

According to the docs, SSL is required to send through Gmail:

> **Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server**
>
> smtp.gmail.com
>   Requires SSL: Yes
>   Requires TLS: Yes (if available)
>   Requires Authentication: Yes
>   Port for SSL: 465
>   Port for TLS/STARTTLS: 587

Reference: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for reply @Wayne Phipps, I can use office 365 as an alternative but that again seems not working with EnableSSL=false.

Comment: I would expect most corporate email providers to require SSL, otherwise credentials would be transmitted in clear text